# Handling many-many relationship in power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerpivot

I’ve 3 tables. Project table consists of 2 columns as project-ID, project Name. Status Table consists of 2 columns as project-ID, status. Risk Table consists of 2 columns as project-ID, risk.

Now I’ve build the model as follows

Status table to project table using one to many relationship
Risk table to project table using one to many relationship

When I try to visualize project-ID, project Name from projects table, status from status Table, Risk from Risk table in Table visualization.

Power BI throws an error as “unable to determine the relationship between 2 or more tables.”

I’m able to drag and drop either risk field or status field in the table visualization.

Comment: Please post your data in a minimal reproducible way that can be copied. Please also include more detail regarding what you have tried. You are giving us nothing to go on.